# Better request to query the last insert

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a better request in mySQL to return the same think that:

```
SELECT chaine FROM etats ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Because this request needs to browse and order all the table, that is slow in a very big table...

I try:

```
SELECT chaine FROM etats WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

But return nothink.
And:

```
SELECT chaine FROM etats WHERE id = MAX(id)
```

Return: " #1111 - Invalid use of group function"

Thanks for help.

Comment: `"this request needs to browse and order all the table"` - There's no index on the *identifier*?  I imagine that's slowing down *everything*, including the other attempts you're making.  This might work: `SELECT chaine FROM etats WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM etats)`, but without an index on `id` that's still going to be slow.  And even with an index I can't imagine how it would be any faster than just an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Yes id is my primary key. So Order By is the faster way ?

Comment: When you look at the query execution plan (I think in MySQL it's with the `EXPLAIN` keyword), what is the actual bottleneck that you're looking to address.  "Faster" isn't a meaningful metric without identifying what specifically needs to be improved.  And if there's *no index* on the identifier in your table then that's *probably* going to be the first improvement to make.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select chaine, max(id) from etats
```

Comment: Mysql libraries like the one built into PHP also has a function mysqli_insert_id() that you can call after the insert, providing you the id created. All fields that are keys or tagged with indexed, should be fast to sort, reverse, min and max on